# Silverlight: How to mantain the same localization for all countries

Tags: silverlight, localization, culture, string-formatting

I need to know how to format a given number (or date, or whatever)
always italian language, no matter in what country the client is...

Example:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Price, StringFormat=C2} />
```

must return "€ 1.520,45" in every country is executed.
even if Italian language is not installed in that machine.

How can i achieve that?
(possibly is better if i can do it application wide)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the UICulture and Culture of the Silverlight application explicitly to ensure that regardless of the user locale the UICulture and Culture would be fixed.

This can be achieved in two ways

1- Set in the object tag on the browser

```
<param name="uiculture" value="it-IT" />
<param name="culture" value="it-IT" />
```

2- Set the thread culture in the `Application_Startup`

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("it-IT");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("it-IT");
```

**Update**: The above does not seem to take effect when using StringFormat. Given this, I would revert to using a custom value converter. Below is a sample

MainPage.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="SLLocalizationTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SLLocalizationTest" 
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <local:DoubleToStringConverter x:Key="DoubleToStringConverter" />
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToStringConverter}, ConverterParameter=C2 }"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToStringConverter} }"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace SLLocalizationTest
{
  public partial class MainPage : UserControl
  {
    public MainPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = this;
    }

    public double Price
    {
      get { return 12353.23; }
    }
  }

  public class DoubleToStringConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
      object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      if (value is double)
      {
        return ((double)value).ToString((string)parameter);
      }      
      return value.ToString();    
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
      object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Even in an environment where no italian language is installed?

Comment: @ccen, yes this will still work, Windows maintains a list of all the UI culture settings for most locales.

Comment: i've added the 2 lines in application startup of a silverlight business application  but the result is still in Dollars : "$ 1,520.45"
the only method i've found is adding 
Me.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("it-IT")
in every constructor of every usercontrol where i need formatting,

is still valid with this way?

Comment: @ccen, did you add the two lines before the Root visual was created? These should be the first two lines in the Application_Startup.

Comment: @ccen, it seems that this is a limitation (bug?) with the StringFormat. For now you need to set the Language. Personally, I would just use a IValueConverter and use ToString to handle the formatting.